# Maven scanned from multiple locations type of warnings

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to develop a project with Maven, which also involves Jetty as a servlet container. But in build time appear warnings like "scanned from multiple locations" which involves a location in the .m2 directory and a location in the target directory created. I'm not sure if they are triggered by using Jetty. How can these warnings be solved?

Comment: similar comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50052838/getting-a-whole-lot-of-scanned-from-multiple-locations-warnings-in-simple-jers

Answer (score 1):

Change the setting `useManifestOnlyJar to false` in the POM, around the tags:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
          <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want ignore the WARN log, you can append below code in `start.ini` file:

```
--exec
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.LEVEL=OFF
```