# Gradle is there a plugin to identify class naming collisions in the configuration

Tags: java, gradle, jetty

In our project we are deploying a Java web app in Jetty. Jetty warns that it can find the same class in multiple locations (see this earlier SO question [Maven Jetty spams warning "scanned from multiple locations"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52402360/7421645)).

We were able to identify that taglibs was in our server classpath as well as being bundled with our application. However we also found some more complicated scenarios, such as dependencies that had bundled common dependencies into their release artifact! And some generated code in a few jars that just had common classes being generated with the same names and classpaths.

Since Jetty is able to tell us these exist, I was wondering if there was a Gradle plugin that might inform us a little faster?