# How do I stop maven-jetty-plugin jetty:run output warnings: scanned from multiple locations

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-jetty-plugin

maven-jetty-plugin  v 11.0.19 is in the myApp-server module,
jetty:run output shows around 80 warnings such as:

```
[WARNING] jakarta.servlet.AsyncEvent scanned from multiple locations: 
jar:file:///C:/Users/tim_m/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api/5.0.2/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api-5.0.2.jar!
jar:file:///C:/Users/tim_m/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api/5.0.2/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api-5.0.2.jar!
```

jetty-server is a declared dependency in the myApp-jettyMain module (the embedded server for production), jetty-jakarta-servlet-api is pulled in by jetty-server;
myApp-jettyMain:jar is a dependency of myApp-server.

Although these scan paths are identical the warnings don't look good & slow up jetty start time.

There's a clue is in the debug output of jetty:run which shows jetty-jakarta-servlet-api is scanned from 2 Container paths ?

```
[DEBUG] Container paths selected:[file:///C:/Users/tim_m/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/toolchain/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api/5.0.2/jetty-jakarta-servlet-api-5.0.2.jar, file:///C:/Users/tim_m/.m2/repository/jakarta/servlet/jsp/jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api/2.0.0/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-2.0.0.jar, file:///C:/Users/tim_m/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/web/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/2.0.0/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar]
```

I presume this is relevant to the warnings?
I've looked at several posts related to this, most refer to earlier jetty versions.
Its usually a problem with dependencies but none of the dependencies I have added to this small sample make reference to these Container paths afaik.

Comment: Possible dup (but maybe not?) https://stackoverflow.com/q/50052838/18157.  You should google _"AsyncEvent scanned from multiple locations"_ and thoroughly check out all the hits for possible help (you should ALWAYS do that with an error message you don't understand).

Comment: Yesterday I googled: [WARNING] jakarta.servlet.AsyncEvent scanned from multiple locations: 
I caught the link you mention, in this case there were dependencies in the pom that could be modified, there aren't any in mine: there's no glassfish so I guess that's drawn in by jetty-maven-plugin or the embedded jetty dependencies ?

Comment: You might have two identical copies of the `jetty-jakarta-servlet-api-5.0.2.jar` library being loaded by different classloaders.  That's pretty much the only thing that could cause this, other than a bug.

Comment: Definitely 2 identical jars from same path in local repo. Question is why and do I want these 80 warnings every time jetty starts ?

Comment: My sample has gwt-jakarta-servlet in the server module, this seems to be causing the problem. If I add the GWT BOM it's gone, but I previously removed the latter because it was replacing jetty 11 embedded dependencies with jetty 9 and adding javax.servlet. This runs ok locally on jetty-maven-plugin or with the embedded jetty in jettyMain, but deployed to cloud GAE the server looks for javax servlets